# Angular upgrade - v10 to v16

Tags: angular, upgrade

I need some clarifications on Angular upgrade. My Angular application is in angular 10 and we have some libraries (developed internally) targeting Angular 10. The requirement is to upgrade to angular 16.

The library files are upgraded to angular 16 and published. I am trying to upgrade the UI application.

As per the angular update guide, I can upgrade only one major version at a time.

How can I upgrade my UI application when I don't have the library projects from V11 to V15? I have only the library projects pointing to version 10 and then V16 in my repository.

Comment: Jumping 6 versions is pretty big. My advice would be to do each upgrade but only really worry about the last one working. In general the upgrades to 11-15 might work but you also might get errors with your libraries. With each version upgrade just be prepared to have some errors you can ignore until you get to v16 to finally tackle them.  Since version 11-15 are just there on the path to get to v16, they aren't too important.